# AWS SNI (server name Indication) via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, sni, amazon-elb

Actually, I want to add different SSL certificates on the same port.
As per the AWS document, SNI is now possible via using Application Loadblancer (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/)

They have specified the steps via AWS console or CLI, but want to perform this via AWS Cloudformation.

I have setup Application Loadblancer via aws document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html) and its working fine. It's just I have to add additional certificate to my 443 port.

Comment: Please were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: no @TundeMichael, I had done it using AWS console only. I didn't find any AWS documentation which can help to setup SNI using cloud formation